# Export Access database to csv in a batch script

Tags: csv, ms-access, export

I want to hear options from you experts on how to export an access database to csv without opening the database and choosing the tables one by one. I have 148 tables where I want to convert the data to csv. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this without at least opening Access so you can interact with it.  Anyway, just create a button on a From, or fire the Macro some other way, and run the script below.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command0_Click()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim oXL As Object
    Dim oWrkBk As Object

    Set db = CurrentDb

    'Create instance of Excel.
    Set oXL = CreateXL

    For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
        If Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then

            'Create workbook with single sheet.
            Set oWrkBk = oXL.Workbooks.Add(-4167) 'xlWBATWorksheet

            'Open the table recordset.
            Set rst = tdf.OpenRecordset

            'In the immediate window display table name and TRUE/FALSE if exported successfully.
            Debug.Print tdf.Name & " - " & QueryExportToXL(oWrkBk.Worksheets(1), , rst, tdf.Name)

            'Save and close the workbook.
            oWrkBk.SaveAs "C:\your_path\" & tdf.Name & ".xlsx"
            oWrkBk.Close

        End If
    Next tdf

End Sub


'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : CreateXL
' Author    : Darren Bartrup-Cook
' Date      : 02/10/2014
' Purpose   : Creates an instance of Excel and passes the reference back.
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function CreateXL(Optional bVisible As Boolean = True) As Object

    Dim oTmpXL As Object

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Defer error trapping in case Excel is not running. '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oTmpXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'If an error occurs then create an instance of Excel. '
    'Reinstate error handling.                            '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER
        Set oTmpXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If

    oTmpXL.Visible = bVisible
    Set CreateXL = oTmpXL

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CreateXL."
            Err.Clear
    End Select


End Function


'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : QueryExportToXL
' Author    : Darren Bartrup-Cook
' Date      : 26/08/2014
' Purpose   : Exports a named query or recordset to Excel.
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function QueryExportToXL(wrkSht As Object, Optional sQueryName As String, _
                                                  Optional rst As DAO.Recordset, _
                                                  Optional SheetName As String, _
                                                  Optional rStartCell As Object, _
                                                  Optional AutoFitCols As Boolean = True, _
                                                  Optional colHeadings As Collection) As Boolean

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim oXLCell As Object
    Dim vHeading As Variant

    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

    If sQueryName <> "" And rst Is Nothing Then

        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Open the query recordset.                               '
        'Any parameters in the query need to be evaluated first. '
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Set db = CurrentDb
        Set qdf = db.QueryDefs(sQueryName)
        For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
            prm.Value = Eval(prm.Name)
        Next prm
        Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset
    End If

    If rStartCell Is Nothing Then
        Set rStartCell = wrkSht.Cells(1, 1)
    Else
        If rStartCell.Parent.Name <> wrkSht.Name Then
            Err.Raise 4000, , "Incorrect Start Cell parent."
        End If
    End If


    If Not rst.BOF And Not rst.EOF Then
        With wrkSht
            Set oXLCell = rStartCell

            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            'Paste the field names from the query into row 1 of the sheet. '
            'Or the alternative field names provided in a collection.      '
            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            If colHeadings Is Nothing Then
                For Each fld In rst.Fields
                    oXLCell.Value = fld.Name
                    Set oXLCell = oXLCell.Offset(, 1)
                Next fld
            Else
                For Each vHeading In colHeadings
                    oXLCell.Value = vHeading
                    Set oXLCell = oXLCell.Offset(, 1)
                Next vHeading
            End If

            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            'Paste the records from the query into row 2 of the sheet. '
            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            Set oXLCell = rStartCell.Offset(1, 0)
            oXLCell.CopyFromRecordset rst
            If AutoFitCols Then
                .Columns.AutoFit
            End If

            If SheetName <> "" Then
                .Name = SheetName
            End If

            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            'TO DO: Has recordset imported correctly? '
            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            QueryExportToXL = True

        End With
    Else

        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'There are no records to export, so the export has failed. '
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        QueryExportToXL = False
    End If

    Set db = Nothing

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure QueryExportToXL."
            Err.Clear
            Resume
    End Select

End Function
```